# Confused how to generate a XML file from a list

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xjc

First of all I used the xjc command to generate a Java Class called 'Site' that correlated with a xsd file that I provided. The command also created a ObjectFactory class.

The XML file that I want to create is rather messy, so I was wondering if there was an easy way to do this.

The XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Sites>
<Site id="1" name="SA" loc="C">
<Hosts>
    <Host id="11">
       <Host_Name>fd</Host_Name>
       <IP_address>10.2</IP_address>
    </Host>
    <Host id="12">
       <Host_Name>rq</Host_Name>
       <IP_address>10.1</IP_address>
    </Host>
</Hosts>
</Site>
<Site id="2" name="QA" loc="H">
<Hosts>
    <Host id="11">
       <Host_Name>fd</Host_Name>
       <IP_address>10.2</IP_address>
    </Host>
    <Host id="12">
       <Host_Name>rq</Host_Name>
       <IP_address>10.1</IP_address>
    </Host>
</Hosts>
</Site>
</Sites>
```

The ObjectFactory generated via the xjc command is:

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {


/**
 * Create a new ObjectFactory that can be used to create new instances of schema derived classes for package: src
 * 
 */
public ObjectFactory() {
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link Site }
 * 
 */
public Site createSite() {
    return new Site();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link Site.Hosts }
 * 
 */
public Site.Hosts createSiteHosts() {
    return new Site.Hosts();
}

/**
 * Create an instance of {@link Site.Hosts.Host }
 * 
 */
public Site.Hosts.Host createSiteHostsHost() {
    return new Site.Hosts.Host();
}

}
```

Now I somehow want to generate the xml file above, but it's not obvious to me how to do so from the ObjectFactory class (or if I should even bother using it).

I'm reading a text file of data formatted like:

```
site_id, name, loc, host_id, h_name, ip
10, dfsd, fdsa, 32, fd, 10
11, dffdsa, fdre, 33, fs, 11
```

And I'm not exactly sure how to generate the XML tree given this. Should I use the ObjectFactory class provided? (It doesn't look look like it would be of any help...).

Otherwise, I thought about looping through the text file to create a List of 'Site' Objects and then somehow outputting it in XML Format. But if there are any easier suggestions, please make them.

Comment: show up your code that what have you tried right now ? or you directly came here for solution !!!

Comment: You can try http://simple.sourceforge.net/ , easier to use for your purpose

Comment: You might check http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing3.html for an example on how to use ObjectFactory

Comment: Where is the Sites factory method in you ObjectFactory class? You either remove it or your XSD does not correspond with provided XML.